# Visual Studio 2013 AngularJS intellisense support

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013

I thought VS 2013 is supposed to have support for angularjs attribute intellisense?  For some reason it's not working for me on the latest version of Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 version 12.0.21005.1

Getting the following validation warning:
Attribute 'ng-app' is not a valid attribute of element 'html'.
Attribute 'ng-view' is not a valid attribute of element 'div'.

Am i missing an xsd reference somewhere?

Comment: Use `data-ng-*` - technically, `ng-*` isn't a valid attribute.

Comment: Yes, this is what I used to do in Visual Studio 2012, I just thought VS 2013 is supposed to have support for this?

Comment: I am also a bit baffled, working now on an angular website, but it can't autocomplete or do any of the functions that are advertised.

Answer (score 65):

I had the same problem and I did the following and it helped.

If you are using ReSharper, you can add an extension that will give you Intellisense, and won't raise a warning.

Top Menu in VS>Resharper>Extension Manager>Search AngularJS
This will add angular js intellisense.

***-------EDIT-------***

Using Resharper 8.2.1
[image: Resharper Menu]

[image]

Comment: In VS 2012 you mean Tools>Extension and Updates > online > Search AngularJS and select resharper?

Comment: Its the same menu. You need the menu for resharper not vs. In the top menu Resharper

Comment: I'm on ReSharper 8.2, but didn't have the ReSharper Gallery under VS>Resharper>Extension Manager. Since this is the only way to install plugins in 8.2, I was at a lose.

I restored the ReSharper Gallery by going to VS>Resharper>Options...>Environment>Extension Manager. I added a new extension source named "My ReSharper Gallery" pointing to https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/api/v2  I couldn't find the address of the service on JetBrain's website or in any documentation.  I only figured it out by going to https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages and looking at the network traffic.

Comment: I've just edited my response with images. This is what you get?

Comment: Will this provide intellisense for JS code as well, or is it only HTML?

Comment: It will provide JS completion too.

Answer (score 20):

I know this is old, but it was still happening for me. To fix it for VS 2013, follow these instructions:

1) Open the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\commonHTML5Types.xsd

2) Find the area in the file that starts with this line:
`<xsd:attribute name="translate">`. Scroll down about 7 lines to find the corresponding closing tag: `</xsd:attribute>`

3) Just **above** the `</xsd:attributeGroup>` closing tag, paste the following lines of code:

```
<xsd:attribute name="ng-app" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-bind-html" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-bind-html-unsafe" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-bind-template" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-checked" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-class" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-class-even" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-class-odd" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-click" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-cloak" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-controller" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-csp" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-dblclick" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-disabled" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-form" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-hide" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-href" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-include" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-init" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-list" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-model" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-mousedown" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-mouseenter" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-mouseleave" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-mousemove" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-mouseover" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-mouseup" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-multiple" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-non-bindable" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-readonly" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-repeat" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-selected" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-show" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-src" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-style" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-switch" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-transclude" vs:category="Angular" />
<xsd:attribute name="ng-view" vs:category="Angular" />
```

Save the file and reopen VS2013. This should fix the issue.

Comment: if somebody don't use resharper - this should be a sollution ;)

Comment: This is the correct answer and doesn't require a 3rd party tool.  The problem is that VS2013 does include Angular support but only for .html pages.  This answer adds the same support for .aspx pages.

Comment: For directives without a value like `ng-cloak` you can add the property `vs:standalone="true"` : `<xsd:attribute name="ng-cloak" vs:category="Angular" vs:standalone="true" />`

Comment: Confirmed this works for Visual Studio 2015 as well.

Comment: This did not work for me in VS2015. Values for ng-attributes look great in .html, but highlighted as normal text in .aspx

Answer (score 17):

I installed http://vswebessentials.com/

created a file called
_reference.js
with content

```
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
/// <reference path="underscore.js" />
```

I learned about it from [The Story Behind _references.js](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using ReSharper, try turning off ReSharper IntelliSense for HTML.

ReSharper > Options > IntelliSense > General > Limited ReSharper IntelliSense

Notes:

- This does not provide AngularJS intellisense in ASP.NET files
- You need to reopen HTML files in VS after the settings have been changed
- Current version of ReSharper is 8.2

Answer (score 9):

You could also just run this from the package manager console in VS 2013: Install-Package AngularJS.Intellisense.

Comment: Probably the right answer.  here is a link https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Intellisense/

Answer (score 5):

Try to tick `Text Editor\HTML\General\Auto list members` in options.

Comment: Auto list members is already checked by default for both HTML and HTML (web Forms).  Besides, it has nothing to do with intellisense.

Comment: For me that was it!, checking Auto List Members option for HTML (default was unchecked).

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old and the question specifically refers to VS 2013, however if you're still running **VS 2010** and want to apply puargs solution you can find the file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\html_5.xsd.

You'll want to add puargs' code within the `<xsd:attributeGroup name="commonHTML5coreAttributeGroup">` section.

Mads Kristensen also discusses [applying this solution to **VS 2012]**[1](http://madskristensen.net/post/angularjs-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2012) and provides a link to an updated version of 2012's commonHTML5Types.xsd in Step 2.

Also note that both puargs and Mads listings are missing an attribute on **ng-view** that causes an "attribute name must be followed by an equal (=) sign" warning. The complete element is: `<xsd:attribute name="ng-view" vs:category="Angular" vs:standalone="true"/>`.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 removes the validation, however it does not include IntelliSense for AngularJS.

> **Support for custom elements, polymer-elements and attributes**
>
> We no longer validate unknown attributers for custom elements as there
>   will be many custom made tags in different frameworks. So there will
>   no longer be squiggles under the unknown elements.
>
> — [Announcing new Web Features in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-4-rc.aspx)

Download [Visual Studio 2013 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921).

Validation is only removed in the HTML editor, not the HTML (Web Forms) editor. This means that, by default, .html files will not have custom element validation, but .aspx pages will. If, like me, you don't think this makes sense, show your support by voting for [custom elements in .aspx files](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6602906-support-custom-elements-in-aspx-files).

Comment: I have VS 2013 Pro Update 4 installed and the squiggles remain under the AngularJS bootstrap <alert> tag in an html file.

Answer (score 1):

Running into the same problem. If you have **ReSharper installed on VS 2013** like me, you can get the instellisense by installing the AngularJS plugin (provided by JetBrains).

**Here's how to do it:**

1. VS2013 > ReSharper > Manage Extension.
2. Search "AngularJS" using Nuget online, then click "Install".

The above should get you what you needed. In case you need image guide, here's the link - http://jeeshenlee.com/2014/07/12/how-to-get-angularjs-intellisense-support-on-resharper/

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried with vs2013, but could work. Working with vs2012.
http://madskristensen.net/post/angularjs-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled resharper intellisense for HTML pages and got angular intellisense back on VS2013

Answer (score 0):

You can also get rid of warnings:

http://madskristensen.net/post/angularjs-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2012