# Visual studio angularjs intellisense not showing up for some methods

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am receiving angular directives like ng-app just fine in my html. Intellisense is working good for them.

I am receiving intellisense for some angular methods like so:

[image: bootstrap method of angular works]

But other methods I am not receiving anything at all, or the wrong stuff.

[image: module method of angular does not]

What could be causing this? I know that module is supposed to be receiving different intellisense.

I have a friend with PHPStorm and he is receiving this intellisense for the module method.

[image: PHPstorm intellisense for angular.module]

Comment: I know it's not an answer to my question, but I've started researching  TypeScript as a solution to the intellisense problem. Not only that, it helps with the type safety of javascript, which is something I always wanted... optional type safety. I can get the intellisense by downloading a nuget package for AngularJs TypeScript definitions, which as a benefit also gives intellisense for Dependency Injected items that I set. Quite cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add angularjs reference to `~/Scripts/_references.js`. This file is configured to be searched for references by JavaScript IntelliSense engine by default (Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript > IntelliSense > References). Just open that file and drag-and-drop angular.js file there (I assume you have it included in your project). Reference will look like following

```
/// <reference path="libs/angular/angular.js" />
```

You also can add references like this to any js file - you'll get IntelliSence there.

Comment: You sir, are amazing. Thanks for responding to this! I thought I had to use typescript just to get intellisense... but typescript lately for me is becoming a headache so I just want the pure javascript.

Comment: Welcome! The following links may be also helpful. https://github.com/jmbledsoe/angularjs-visualstudio-intellisense/ http://stackoverflow.com/a/21805152/951186 But for me I've chosen typescript for my current project. And for good: ngconf 2015 stated that angular 2.0 is coming out on typescript.