# How I get proper AngularJS intellisense support in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

By proper I mean intellisense for HTML and JavaScript, i.e.

Typing `<div ng-></div>` should show intellisense as below.

[image]

and typing (in .js files) `angular.` should promt me with intellisense for `controller`, `config` etc as seen below (i'm after a more accurate intellisense than shown below actually, it seem to be giving me regular JS support, not Angular).

[image]

I'l also like support for your own controllers, so in the case you've defined your `customController` and/or service with your `customFunction`, i'd like that to be shown as well.

Here you can read about [Using AngularJS in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/02/05/using-angularjs-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx), the article explains how to copy-paste a special angular.intellisense.js file into your C:\ drive.

[Here's a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21805152/2874896) regarding how to enable AngularJS support for ReSharper  in Visual Studio. When I try this I only get the HTML intellisense, I get *nothing* for JS files to work.

Mads Kristensen points out [The story behind _references.js](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) in VS that will add JavaScript intellisense for the files you like.

I get the impression that all these ways can be solutions to the same  problem: Getting AngularJS support in VS, *but which is the most neat approach?* Currently i've tried all of them and I feel there something i'm doing wrong, as i'm not very impressed so far.

Thanks a bunch for any help!

Comment: I have the opposite problem, I get `ng-` intellisense when editing HTML and would really like to turn it off.

Comment: @paul are you using ReSharper?

Comment: no resharper, and I cannot see any extensions or add-ins that might be doing it either. Have also checked the hmtl5types.xsd and it's not coming from there.

Comment: See if my answer here can help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830266/angularjs-intellisense-not-working-on-visual-studio-2015/31615630#31615630

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging angular.min.js file directly on the top of your .js file

surely it'll enable all the inbuilt intellisense, not sure about the custom controllers or directives you make.

hope it helps you :)

[write this at the top of .js file starting from 3 forward slashes => ///](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO3uz.jpg)