# Visual Studio 2013 AngularJS IntelliSense

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimamte Edition to develop a new AngularJS project. The problem is that I can't use intellisense. I tried a lot of different things that I read in internet and StackOverflow. First of all this

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/02/05/using-angularjs-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

After that I read and tried everything that is here.

[Visual Studio 2013 AngularJS intellisense support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709538/visual-studio-2013-angularjs-intellisense-support)

I don't get any error or warning. Basically I can't use Intellisense with my project and I think that I referenced it in my project correctly.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Sample AngularJS project using Visual Studio</title>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app ="myApp">

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller("listController", ["$scope", "projects", function ($scope, projects) {
    $scope.<<Here I don't get Intellisense completion>>
```

The only difference that I saw is that I used to have Resharper installed but not anymore. Thank you